# use lambda in function template, can't deduce type, makeSet() use case

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, type-deduction

What I want to achieve is a makeSet() function accepting three arguments, a pair of iterator, and a function that transforms the value.

One use case could be creating a set from a sequence of values and do transformation, eg, convert a `std::map<K,V>` to `std::set<std::pair<V,K>>.`

The client code may look like

```
auto s = makeSet(hash.begin(), hash.end(),
    [](std::pair<int,int> x) { return std::make_pair(x.second, x.first); });
```

my current attempt is as follow,

```
// (commented code are some other *failed* attempt).
template <typename Iterator,
        typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
        template<typename ... > class Monad, typename R >
        // typename R, typename Monad = std::function<R(T)> >
std::set<R> makeSet(Iterator first, Iterator last, Monad<R,T> f) {
    std::set<R> res;
    for (; first != last; ++first) res.insert(f(*first));
    return res;
}
```

but unfortunately does not work. The problem looks like failing to deduce R.

Is there any solution or workaround?
I will be very grateful if you can tell me the right way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of a lambda expression is a unnamed class type (its closure type), not `std::function`. You cannot therefore deduce `std::function` or `Monad` from it.

Your best bet would be to do what the standard library does, and simply accept anything as the predicate:

```
template <
  class Iterator,
  class UnaryFunction
>
auto makeSet(Iterator first, Iterator last, UnaryFunction f) -> std::set<decltype(f(*first))>
{
  std::set<decltype(f(*first))> res;
  for (; first != last; ++first) res.insert(f(*first));
  return res;
}
```

Note that you may have to wrap the `decltype` in `std::remove_reference` and/or `std::remove_cv` to cover all corner cases (or, as suggested by [@Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk), `std::decay`).

Also, to avoid re-inventing the wheel, you might want to take a look at the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library.

Comment: Oh, the beloved and sometime picky decltype!!

Comment: Does range mean use range object instead of a pair of iterator, similar to [this](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html), or something different?

Comment: I would just use `std::decay_t<decltype(blah)>`, as `decay_t` makes types suitable for storage.  A second point is that you should almost never deduce the type of `std::function`; `std::function` is a type-erasure class, and type deduction and type erasure are opposites.  Deducing what type to erase to is a sign of a design flaw.  You erase because you need a fixed type here; you deduce because you know the exact type here.  If you know the exact type, 999/1000 times you don't need a fixed type there.

Answer (score 1):

"The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain." -- Scotty, Star Trek III.

There's no need to over-design the template function, like that. Just use a forwarding reference, and let your C++17 compiler figure everything out.

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// (commented code are some other *failed* attempt).
template <typename Iterator, typename Lambda>
auto makeSet(Iterator first, Iterator last, Lambda &&f) {

    typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(first->first)>::type const_first_t;

    typedef typename std::remove_const<const_first_t>::type first_t;

    typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(first->second)>::type second_t;

    typedef std::pair<first_t, second_t> R;


    std::set<R> res;

    for (; first != last; ++first) res.insert(f(*first));
    return res;
}


void foo()
{
    std::map<int, int> m;

    std::set<std::pair<int, int>> s =
        makeSet(m.begin(), m.end(),
            [](const auto &x)
            {
                return std::make_pair(x.second, x.first);
            });

}
```

Comment: `R` is supposed to be the decayed type of `f(*first)`, not whatever it is you've written here.

Comment: Good point! Though I would prefer more concise version. That's why I can't come up with similar solution, it's too dauntingly looking for the uninitiated.

Comment: As @Barry pointed out, more general R is needed, though the idea is similar.

Comment: Also, could this solution be adapted to C++03, -- not using `decltype` -- without too much hassle?

Comment: I don't see an easy path for any version of this in C++03. Not unless you explicitly specify the type of everything, in additional template parameters. Bottom line: upgrade your compiler :-)